# Running an official sample code returns "Invalid reporting query"

Tags: report, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I've been trying to run some sample code from the official docs.

But I get an error:
Invalid reporting query: ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT. (file Code.gs, line 18)

The official sample from the official doc:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/adsapp/adsapp_report

My code:

```
function main() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Report output");
   //var report = AdsApp.report("SELECT Id, PolicySummary FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING LAST_30_DAYS");
  var report = AdsApp.report("SELECT Clicks, Impressions, AverageCpc, HourOfDay FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING LAST_MONTH");
   report.exportToSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet());
   Logger.log("Report available at " + spreadsheet.getUrl());
}
```